# AngularJS open modal dialog on button click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to do something, that I'm guessing should be fairly easy, but I can't figure it out.  All I want to do is open a modal on the click of a button.  I'm following this example.  http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-modal-dialog.html

Here's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap.modal"]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.open = function () {
    $scope.showModal = true;
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $scope.showModal = false;
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $scope.showModal = false;
};
});
```

Here's my view:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>

<div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting the error message Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.  And the modal shows on the page when it loads.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hum this problem doesn't appear on my computer. Can you show us more code pls ?

Comment: @John' What other code would you like to see?

Comment: Hum yeah, maybe you have lots of code. Just a question, have you insert a directive "modal" in your code ?

Comment: @John' no I haven't.  It didn't show that in the example.  How do I do that?  Sorry I'm really new to AngularJS.  I get lost easily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first line, you use "modal=" . It is a directive, you need to implement it in you code. (See here : [AngularJS reusable modal bootstrap directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483979/angularjs-reusable-modal-bootstrap-directive) )

For the problem " Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined", it is a dependency problem I think. A similar problem here : [Angularjs: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895235/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-homecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-und)

If you want implement a modal dialogbox, I advice you to see the official Bootstrap-Angular Doc here : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Ok, that fixed my error message.  I've tried the first article with the same results.  I'm wondering if I'm missing something from my project and that is why it's not working?

Comment: Your project looks good because you haven't error (so no dependency problem). All is there. About your modal, you have 2 choices : implement the "modal directive', or use $uibModal (more simple, see the doc (cf link above)). Code is strange (a controller specially for the modal) but simple !

Comment: thanks.  You gave me a lot to look over.  I'm sure it will help me solve the problem.